# How can I style different colors for 5n+1, 5n+2, 5n+3, 5n+4, 5n+5, in an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS application that contains home feed and detail pages.

I styled the list in home feed using `:nth-child(an+b)`.

```
.home-feed li :nth-child(5n+1) {
  background-color: #949CF6;
}

.home-feed li :nth-child(5n+2) {
  background-color: #F499A7;
}

.home-feed li :nth-child(5n+3) {
  background-color: #FFD89C;
}

.home-feed li :nth-child(5n+4) {
  background-color: #8FEADB;
}

.home-feed li :nth-child(5n+5) {
  background-color: #5485FD;
}
```

Now, each `li` in the home feed has a detail page, and I want to style the same color for it as well.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do u think that nth-child won't be helpful? Did u try it?

Comment: I can just do li;nth-child(5n+1){color:red;} and such for my home feed, but this doesn't work for the detail page of each box in the feed.  

So I added `className={`list${this.props.id}`}`.(sorry, backticks are not working)  This means I get list1, list2, list3...as a css class name.  Now I don't know how I can dynamically style them.

Comment: Sorry don't understand? does your style change with class name? then you have to manually write those rules. Like: home-list, detail-list etc.

Comment: Please provide some code.. We can't guess what u did.

Comment: Right, I edited my question!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nth-child()`

```html
<style> 
.list>li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background: red;
}
.list>li:nth-child(5n+2) {
    background: green;
}
.list>li:nth-child(5n+3) {
    background: blue;
}
.list>li:nth-child(5n+4) {
    background: gray;
}
.list>li:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background: yellow;
}
</style>

<ul class='list'>
<li>The first li.</li>
<li>The second li.</li>
<li>The third li.</li>
<li>The fourth li.</li>
<li>The fifth li.</li>
<li>The sixth li.</li>
<li>The seventh li.</li>
<li>The eight li.</li>
<li>The ninth li.</li>
<ul>
```

*Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector*

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using javascript as well, like this.

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
var items = list.childNodes;
items = Array.prototype.filter.call(items, function(item) {
    if (item.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE) return item;
});

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) items[i].style.color = 'red';
    else if (i % 5 == 1) items[i].style.color = 'yellow';
    else if (i % 5 == 2) items[i].style.color = 'magenta';
    else if (i % 5 == 3) items[i].style.color = 'green';
    else if (i % 5 == 4) items[i].style.color = 'blue';
}
```